# cannot authenticate with new user in mongo

Tags: mongodb

```
> use failsafereports;
> db.createUser({ user : 'readonly', pwd: 'readonly', roles : ['read']})
Successfully added user: { "user" : "readonly", "roles" : [ "read" ] }
> show users;
{
    "_id" : "failsafereports.readonly",
    "user" : "readonly",
    "db" : "failsafereports",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "read",
            "db" : "failsafereports"
        }
    ]
}
> db.auth('readonly','readonly')
Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 }
0
```

I am creating a new user.
It shows when I use `show users`
But when I try to `auth`, it fails.

any ideas?

I've read around the internet about this problem occurring from the command line, but couldn't find one that happens from mongo shell.

Comment: Please switch to "use failsafereports" and then execute "db.auth('readonly','readonly')".

Comment: @notionquest I am - did not include that line.. but I am working on failsafereports database. I will add it in the question.